# mobile webapp into playstore, itunes ect

Tags: android, ios, mobile, web-applications

dear lovely people on stackoverflow.

i am currently doing research on differences between native mobile applications and webapplications. so far, i already found a lot. from my perspective as a frontend webdeveloper, i wonder about one thing, which i can't find any infos on.

when i publish a webapp under my domain, fully responsive and insert the metatags:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

it is possible to launch my app in fullscreen view on mobile devices. this applies just, if a user saved my mobile webapp to his/her homescreen as a bookmark.

android and ios then create something looking like an applauncher on the devices homescreen, which is fully suitable for my application.

but as the app-stores are big markets too, i wonder, if it would be possible, to upload just an "applauncher" to the respective stores.

the web-app would be still hosted by my server/domain, and the published store app is nothing more, than a downloadable webapp launcher, or more a chrome/safari-launcher in full screen view.

is that somehow possible?

would be glad, if anyone could tell me his/her experience.

ps: sorry for my english!

Comment: You can't do this on Appple's store

Comment: thanks for the info! - do you know, if it's possible to do that in playstore? or windows mobile store?

Comment: You could trivially write a 5 line app that just launches the browser on Android.

Comment: thanks a lot - that's exactly, what i am aiming to. but regarding to style-guidlines, restrictions and similar, i am asking myself if that's really possible,... i thought, maybe someone has made experience with that "solution" before. the submitted "app" then would be only a "launch the systembrowser in fullscreen app and force it to a certain domain"... i just thought, such an app would be rejected immediately from the official stores.